# gstreamer rtsp stream, server runs but client crashes

Tags: linux, plugins, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, rtsp

I am following a video tutorial online to stream low latency video and audio using gstreamer.

Here is the video link:  https://youtu.be/mNQTORvhQ6Q

I have installed all the gstreamer dependencies and plugins on both the client and server and the rtsp package on the server also. The server runs with no issues but when I try run the client it has an error and ends the pipeline. I have tried some video only examples and it does indeed work so it's something to do with the pipeline I am using.

Here is the server pipeline running from a Raspberry Pi 4:

```
Ran from inside the /gst-rtsp-server-1.14.4/examples folder: 
./test-launch --gst-debug=0    "( alsasrc device=hw:2,0  ! "audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=48000" ! audioconvert ! opusenc ! rtpopuspay  name=pay1 pt=97  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "image/jpeg,width=800,height=600,frame-rate=30/1" !  rtpjpegpay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

Here is the pipeline on the client, which is a Ubuntu PC:

```
gst-launch-1.0  rtspsrc latency=0 location=rtsp://192.168.127.219:8554/test   name=src src.  !  "application/x-rtp, channels=1, media=audio, rate=48000, encoding-name=OPUS" ! rtpjitterbuffer  ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! audioconvert !   jackaudiosink   src. ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG"  ! rtpjitterbuffer  !    rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec !  videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

It has these errors:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJackAudioSink:jackaudiosink0: Jack server not found
Additional debug info:
gstjackaudiosink.c(355): gst_jack_ring_buffer_open_device (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJackAudioSink:jackaudiosink0:
Cannot connect to the Jack server (status 17)
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I have tested the output of jackaudiosink on its own with a test tone and it also works fine, so I assume it's specifically something about this pipeline that I haven't got quite right :(

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put 'autoaudiosink' instead of 'jackaudiosink'? Like that:

```
gst-launch-1.0  rtspsrc latency=0 location=rtsp://192.168.127.219:8554/test   name=src src.  !  "application/x-rtp, channels=1, media=audio, rate=48000, encoding-name=OPUS" ! rtpjitterbuffer  ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! audioconvert !   autoaudiosink   src. ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG"  ! rtpjitterbuffer  !    rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec !  videoconvert ! autovideosink
```